# How can you take a manually inputted array and sort it?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, input

Here's my current code:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
 try
      {
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of numbers in the array");
        int arraySize2 = keyboard.nextInt ();
        System.out.println("Please enter the numbers in the array seperately.");
        int[] array = new int[arraySize2];
        for(int b=0; b<=arraySize2-1; b++){
          array[b] = keyboard.nextInt(20);}    
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length -1; i++){
          int minPos = i;
          for (int j = i; j < array.length; j++){
            if (array[j] < array[minPos])
              minPos = j; }       
          // swaps minimum value with current location
          int temp = array[i];
          array[i] = array[minPos];
          array[minPos] = temp; }
      }
      catch( ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e ) 
      {

      }
}
```

The problem that I think I have is somewhere when I manually input the array. But I get hazy around there? Does anyone see a problem? I based this code off of a method that took a random array and sorted it. Thanks.

Comment: `keyboard.nextInt(20);` reads in a number in base 20 - are you sure you want this? Other than that the code has no problems (well, except the formatting..); you could use `Arrays.sort()` instead of the manual selection sort.

Comment: @Anthales but this might be homework so `Arrays.sort()` is not allowed :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a `TreeMap<Integer, Integer>` and keep entering values to it. Finally use an iterator or `for each` loop to print out or use those numbers later.

Or you can use a binary search tree and keep inserting data into it. Finally do an in-order traversal.